# swaggerwcf only works with newtonsoft 8.0.3.0 in a multiproject solution

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, swagger-wcf

I am working in a multiproject solution. There's a main project and the rest is referenced (as existing projects).

In two projects I had newtonsoft 9.0.1.0, then we decided to integrate [swaggerwcf](https://github.com/abelsilva/swaggerwcf) in one of the projects (that has newtonsoft).
I intalled the nugget package for swaggerwcf, but when I tried to go to "/api-docs", I received an error(something like request couldnt be proccess), then I decided to downgrade the version of newtonsoft to 8.0.3.0(it's the minimum version admited by swaggerwcf) and it works but I want to use newtonsoft 9.0.1.0 in both projects.

Suaggerwcf only works with the minimun version of newtonsoft 8.0.3.0. in this solution. I've tried in other solutions(with one project) and works with other versions of newtonsoft.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, what exactly is your question?
have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how ask a good answearble question.

Comment: Next week I'll try the mxmissile answer(bindingredirect). There's not an easy way to ask the question but I think the title summarize my problem. In the Swaggerwcf web page it's indicated that they works with newtonsoft >= 8.0.3.0 but in my solution only does with 8.0.3.0 and I want it working with 9.0.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

[According to nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SwaggerWcf/), 8.0.3 and newer should work. If you have not, try adding a binding redirect as described in [this blog post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2014/nov/29/updating-assembly-redirects-with-nuget). Go to the Package Manager Console for your project and use the `Add-BindingRedirect` command.

Comment: Binding redirect didn't work, I think something is messed up in my solution. Now I have no time for the api documentation so for the time being I'll freeze this part of the development.